# How can I anidate an AND inside an OR in search function? In Odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to anidate an **AND** operator inside an **OR**, in search function of odoo 9.

I have these two conditions:

```py
A = self.env['sale.order'].search(['&', ('state', '=', 'done'), ('id', '>', my_id)])
B = self.env['sale.order'].search([('date_order', '>', my_date)])
```

These conditions work fine per separate, but I need **A** OR **B**

I have tried this:

```py
C = self.env['sale.order'].search(['|', ('date_order', '>', my_date), ('&', ('state', '=', 'done'), ('id', '>', my_id))])
```

That doesn't work. It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: "Invalid leaf ('&', ('state', '=', 'done'), ('id', '>', my_id))" while evaluating
```

What is the correct way to set the condition?

Comment: @Odedra It was a mistake of copy&paste. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it always use the operator before the two tuple:

```
    C = self.env['sale.order'].search(['|', ('date_order', '>', my_date), '&', ('state', '=', 'done'), ('id', '>', my_id)])
```

EDITS :

this is the same as:

```
    ('date_order', '>', my_date)  OR (('state', '=', 'done') AND ('id', '>', my_id))
```

Example :

```
     A and (B or ( C AND D))

     A and (B or (AND, C, D))

     A and,( or, B, AND, C, D)

     and, A, or, B, AND, C, D
```